# Why does DATE_SUB function not work for mysql query with node js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql2, planetscale

I have a datetime field in a MySQL database table on Planetscale. I want to return the datetime value after some time has been subtracted from it using the DATE_SUB function. This works in the database console on Planetscale's website but is not working from my node js server request.

Server code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');  
mysql.query('SELECT DATE_SUB(log_time,INTERVAL 4 HOUR) AS time FROM time_table;',[], function(err, records){
   if (err) {
      console.log(err);
   }
   else {
      console.log(records);
   }
})
```

And this is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE time_table (
    log_time DATETIME
);
```

But is not subtracting the 4 hours as I am expecting and as it does on the db console on Planetscale's website. Is this an issue with Planetscale, MySQL, MySQL2, node js, or something else? Thanks.

Comment: Check your data types?   Is there a date that is actually a string in your node?

Comment: This sounds like a time zone issue. What happens if you do `SELECT CAST(DATE_SUB(...) AS CHAR) AS time`?

Comment: @easleyfixed They have the table definition in the question.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see what the node expects it to be is my point.  Yes it is SUPPOSE to be a date, but what does his node think it is I wonder?

Comment: But the timezone thing could be a real issue if you are talking about planet times, so yeah, we only have "not subtracting 4 hours" , ok, how many did it subtract, or did you get a different error?

Comment: There was no error, it just subtracted no time at all.

Comment: Are you sure of the current data in the table? Try changing your query to include `log_time` in the results so you can compare... `SELECT log_time, DATE_DUB(...`

Answer (score -1):

Seems my issue was rooted in the fact that there are different base times for the results of the query.
If I were to just enter `SELECT log_time AS time FROM time_table;` then the PlanetScale console will return a different time than the results output by node js query result.

I needed to subtract 4 hours to get the Planetscale time into my timezone, but coincidentally the node js results were another 4 hours ahead of planetscale. Thus, when I subtracted 4 hours it appeared to me that no time was being subtracted at all. In reality I just needed to subtract 8 hours in the node query. I guess there is some automatic time zone adjustments going on that make the output that nodes gives different from PlanetScale, but I have solved my issue.